# convert date (from datefield ) J2ME to sql date

Tags: java-me

hye, I need to convert date taken from a datefield (J2ME) and convert it to sql date to save in my database, but it's impossible for me to use sql date in j2me 
any ideas please

i tried to extract the date

```
String getDateString(Date date) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(date);

    int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int second = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    if(month<10){
    return new String(day+"-0"+month+"-"+year+"");}
    else 
                return new String(day+"-"+month+"-"+year+"");

            }
```

then I send it via url

```
hc = (HttpConnection) Connector.
open(url + "nom=" + tfNom.getString() + "&type=" +                 myCh.getString(myCh.getSelectedIndex())+ "&date_debut=" + datec + "&date_fin=" + date_fin.getString() );
```

but in my database i found date 00-00-0000!!

Comment: I updated my question , you may take a look

Comment: Confirm the value sent from your client (log, alert, breakpoint...) and at server add a breakpoint to check how the value is received.